# How ISP sees the HTTPS traffic?

Tags: ssl, https, browsing

If I am visiting a `https` url say `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7HKoqNJtMTQ`. What exactly  my ISP will see ?

Answer (score 11):

You can always install [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and see what's going out of your Internet-facing network interface for yourself.

[This Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858102/with-https-are-the-url-and-the-request-headers-protected-as-the-request-body-is) post gives you specific details.  The destination host you are connecting to will be known, as it's part of the certificate involved in the SSL setup.  That's the "www.youtube.com" part of the URL.  The rest of the specific URL isn't visible to your ISP, but if you are using your ISP's DNS servers, your ISP will be able to know you at least made a DNS lookup to that site.  A DNS lookup cannot be tracked back to a specific URL but keep in mind some sites put different types of content on different servers (such as [Bing putting all explicit content on its own domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bing)) and that could implicate you.  Use a non-ISP DNS such as OpenDNS if you can.

This is assuming you've verified that the certificate presented by the server is the one you are expecting.  SSL proxies (i.e. "man-in-the-middle") are possible but they will substitute a different certificate - which is on you to check for, especially if the substituted certificate is part of the plethora of "trusted root certificates" recognized by most browsers.

Comment: thanks for the reply, could you plz explain "but if you are using your ISP's DNS servers, your ISP will be able to know you at least made a DNS lookup to that site."

Comment: Each URL requires a DNS lookup to translate the domain name into an IP address, i.e. if you type http://superuser.com into a browser, the browser must translate the "superuser.com" into an IP and it issues a DNS lookup to do that.  This causes a small UDP-based query to go to the IP's listed as your DNS server, which may be given to you via DHCP by your provider.  So if you want to trust your ISP the least possible you'd want to avoid using your ISP's DNS server.

Comment: How to know what DNS server my browser looks up?

Comment: Also, even if I am using ISP's DNS server, they will only know the destination host not the complete url. correct ?

Comment: Your browser uses whatever DNS server your network adapter is set to (Windows) or whatever's in /etc/resolv.conf (Linux and maybe OS X).  And yes, they'll only know the destination host not the complete url.

Comment: It's worth noting that if an ISP did somehow manage to create an ssl certificate for a domain they didn't own, that certificate authority would be dropped by all browsers when/if it comes to light - like in the case of DigiNotar.

Answer (score 1):

#### wildcard attack

If the ssl certificate of the destination site is compromised, e.g. by a wildcard certificate owned by a 3rd party, the confidentiality can be compromised on the way to the destination side. (e.g. see [this article](http://www.darknet.org.uk/2011/08/hackers-get-hold-of-wildcard-google-ssl-certificate-could-hijack-gmail-accounts/))

#### company use case

If your ISP is your company, all your traffic may become visible for the company.

Think about a setup, there an additional root certificate owned by the company is deployed to the browser key store. Using this certificate the attack described is easily possible.

In this case a ssl enabled reverse proxy like squid can be used to crack up your encrypted connection.

This is under some circumstances a valid setup, because it allows the use of security systems (e.g. malware scanner) also for ssl encrypted traffic.

The use of such a setup depends on legal restriction in the specific county. In Germany the "Betriebsrat" (employees representatives) have to acknowledge this.